# Python get screenshot from active page's element

Tags: javascript, python, screenshot

i want to take screenshot of django active page's elements. I research about selenium and playwright but they opening the pages on new browser. The page on which I want to take the screenshot has dynamic information and it is constantly changing, so it is not appropriate to take a screenshot by opening it on a new page. Each user will enter different information on the opened page and take a screenshot of the relevant element.

Here want i want to do;

> 1- Take screenshot of div with JS(OK)

> 2- Send POST Request to django url with JS to PYTHON(Need help -,- )

> 3- And send this image to slack(OK)

capturing div via html2canvas;

```
function capture() {
          html2canvas(document.getElementById("main"), {
              letterRendering: 1,
              allowTaint: true,
              useCORS: true,
          })
              .then(function (canvas) {
                  document.getElementById("result").src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.5);
              })
              .catch((e) => {
                  alert(e);
              });
      }
```

Comment: check this tutorial this will help you https://www.tutorialspoint.com/creating-a-screenshot-taking-website-in-django#:~:text=Here%20in%20views.py%2C%20we,screenshot%20that%20we%20just%20took.

Comment: i research about pyautogui too, but it's capturing whole page

Comment: Do you need this feature inside your product? Or do you just need this functionality for testing purposes / reproduction of user's bugs?

Comment: @yevgeniykosmak i need this feature inside my project for quick announcement process

Comment: Without this feature, users have to manually take screenshots and share them on slack. Announcement time required as it is important

Comment: Then it's not a question about Django. You couldn't do it on the back-end side because it definitely has no access to the state of the webpage in your client's browser. I can give you some hints about doing that on the JS side if you want.

Comment: I think I conveyed what I want to do wrong. There is a page with an announcement template, and in case of a possible problem, the information on the page is entered manually and the text in the textbox changes, each user takes a screenshot of the div for a different problem and sends it. Here I want to take a screenshot of the div with javascript and send the image with python and webhook.

Comment: Then please update your question and make it more concrete. Do you want some advice about how to capture a screenshot with JS? Or how to send it to Django? Or how to process it and save it to filesystem / DB / 3rd-party?

Comment: sorry i updated the post. I need learn "how to send it to django" part.

Comment: If you have a Django app, then the user is looking at an image that YOU created, right?  Why does there need to be a screenshot at all?

Comment: @altintash You should also update the tags.

Comment: @timroberts they looking at to a table i have created, and changing rows on it. -Yengeniv i'm removing django tag, i wantto take a screenshot with JS and send it the image with POST request in python.

Comment: You can use html2canvas to make a copy of your DOM in an HTML5 canvas, then grab the canvas.  https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: @timroberts its not enough for me i need to send divs image to slack with one button